# How to define a dependency in CMake only on build system not on target system

Tags: cmake

I have the following problem: I build an SDK using CMake. During the build process a public header file that is later shipped to clients gets generated by a custom_target. This header file is needed by client applications thus also example applications that are shipped as part of the SDK. Within my build system  therefore example applications currently express the dependency to the target generating the header so that it gets generated before trying to build the example application:

```
set(TARGET MyExample)
set(SOURCES ${TARGET}.cpp)
add_executable(${TARGET} ${SOURCES})
add_dependencies(${TARGET} InterfaceHeaderGenerator)
# ... more code
```

Now on a client system the file generated by the 'InterfaceGenerator' of course is already present and therefore this dependency is invalid.

I am searching for a way to be able to ship my CMake files to a customer in a way he can use them without maintaining 2 different copies of CMakeLists.txt files for 'development' and 'client' mode.

I am aware this could probably be solved using generator expressions in connection with CPack. However CPack I cannot use because it lacks another feature I need: Being able to ship and install THE SAME target in several packages.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Guard this `add_dependency()` call with `if(BUILDING_SDK)` and have this variable set to `OFF` by default and `ON` in your case.